# Where do you find the app id / tenantId for an azure function?

Tags: azure-functions

If i'm using an azure function that is based on a consumption plan, where would I find the application ID and tenantID?  In this case, it's not connected to any app service.

At this time, I need the info to retrieve a token to access a key vault locally.  Azure function does provide a service principal, but I can only use that to retrieve the token successfully on the deploy azure function.  However, when I run it locally the rest call fails.  Also note: I'm not doing this in .net so I can't rely on the .net library that does this automatically for you.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: so you cannot use managed service identity or service principal? i dont get it

Comment: If your application is deployed to azure, you can use the managed service identify which is a service principal to retrieve the token to access a key vault via MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET.  However, this approach doesn't work run you run it locally.  So the alternative is to request a token via AAD however I don't know what the app id and tenant ID would be for azure function on a consumption plan which is not attached to any app.

Comment: I guess you can grant your identity access to the key vault ? Depends on what kind of email you're using. The tenantid is the Azure Active directory id, you can get it from the properties of the AAD. To get the service principal, go to app permissions (in the ADD) and you will find all the applications

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to fetch the MSI credentials from outside the function app. One thing you could try is to create an HTTP trigger that returns the values of `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET`. That will allow you to at least know what they are for simulating your function code locally.